# How to reverse sort order in column view

Tags: macos, finder

In OS X Finder (Yosemite), I want to browse files in column view, arranged by kind, and sorted by filename Z-A.  How can I change this from the default A-Z sorting?  I've tried switching to list view and reversing it there, but when I switch back to column view, it goes back to A-Z.

Comment: I was just about to ask the same question. I want to sort the date in ascending order. PathFinder will do the job, but I think it’s over the top for what should be a simple requirement.

Comment: Any solutions yet?